# Puppeteer: multiple user requests to the same Chromium instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless

To hopefully save on system resources I want to run user requests through the same Chromium version in Puppeteer.

If a user submits a form on my site which calls Puppeteer, and Chromium is already running, how can I use the same Chromium instance up to a maximum of 4 tabs?

If there are more than 4 tabs open in the Chromium instance then I want to launch a new Chromium instance.

How can I achieve this? Would I need to store the `browserWSEndpoint` of the Chromium instance to a file and then retrieve it every time a new user submits a request? (This would be using `browserWSEndpoint` with `puppeteer.connect()`).

If I have to do it this way, lets say there are 2 Chromium browsers active. The first most recent browser has the maximum four open tabs, so I could not use this browser. I would then check the next `browserWSEndpoint` and, if there are less than 4 open tabs, create a new page; and if not, launch a new browser.

Does that sound OK?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda which would save you cost , make sure to avoid the 30 seconds timeout of lambda if you are going to be using API Gateway.

https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda

NodeJS

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let result = null;
  let browser = null;

  try {
    browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
      headless: chromium.headless,
    });

    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(event.url || 'https://example.com');

    result = await page.title();
  } catch (error) {
    return context.fail(error);
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  return context.succeed(result);
};
```

Comment: Interesting. How does using lambda save costs/resources? I got this working very similar to the way I described, by adding a browserWSEndpoint to a file and creating a new endpoint when 4 tabs are open in current chromium instance. It works well., but if I can save resources doing it another way that'd be great.