# Reuse a puppeteer instance (created by another module, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The following Q&A's are related, but don't quite answer my question:

- [Puppeteer - Using only 1 browser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170403/puppeteer-using-only-1-browser-instance)
- [reuse browser instance puppeterr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122534/reuse-browser-instance-puppeterr)
- [How to "hook in" puppeteer into a running Chrome instance/tabS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922410/how-to-hook-in-puppeteer-into-a-running-chrome-instance-tab)
- [Puppeteer: multiple user requests to the same Chromium instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453427/puppeteer-multiple-user-requests-to-the-same-chromium-instance)

Also, it seems to me that this topic goes beyond this specific use case, probably a thing of Node itself, so I will be happy for links to a broader explanation.

Anyway: My Node app uses a module, which uses [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). I can supply launch params to it, but cannot access it later (or at least don't know how, or if even possible). This obviously runs it, creates a new page, and does its thing. Then I need to use Puppeteer directly, to render specific HTML given to it. Now, I could `puppeteer.launch()` and `browser.newPage()`, but this would create another Puppeteer instance (..right?). How can use/access the instance created by the mentioned module? Or, is there a way to create a single Pup instance and have other code use it by default, perhaps?

Comment: `newPage()` opens a new tab
https://pocketadmin.tech/en/puppeteer-open-link-in-new-tab/
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v13.5.0/docs/api.md#browsernewpage

`page.bringToFront()` may be useful in your journey down the road

Comment: if the module you mention is one you wrote, you can simply use module.exports = {} to expose the function to other files, mainly app
if it's an npm module, you will need to check the documentation for the answer

Comment: @joeycrash135 I didn't write the module using Pupeteer. That would be easy. I am trying to hookup to a Pup instance spawned by a public module.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,so trying further to answer my question I traversed through variables of the module which spawns puppeteer. In my case, we this is [whatsapp-web.js](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/). When the client is initialize()d, `waclient.pupBrowser._connection._url` is the value to pass to `browserWSEndpoint` parameter of `puppeteer.connect(options)`.
The browser then can be `const browser = await pup.connect({browserWSEndpoint: waBrowserURL});`. Also, `const pup = require('puppeteer')` is necessary.

Or better, I can just directly use `waclient.pupBrowser`, which is the browser instance created by whatsapp-web.js.

So, while this does solve my case, I am not sure how to proceed in scenarios, where the browser is not exposed/accessible as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to export / import.

In the module *where you launch your browser instance* you should **export the variable** *that holds that browser object*, so you could **import it in another file** before reusing it.

Check the "**Using export from**" section at the end of the examples => [export - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) 
for some hint on how to do that.

Anyways if the module is not one of yourself it will be harder to do as you will need to figure out how this browser instance is **used** and **disposed** inside that specific module.

If you can figure that out and if the module that you use **exports an** `object` you may just **add a method to that object to return it's browser instance**.

If the module that you use appears to close the browser instance and relaunch it at times it may be easier to not bother trying to retrieve that browser instance from it and simply import puppeteer to launch a browser instance on which you will have full controll whithout the risk of crashing the other module or your app.